# How to combine two where clauses which uses and/or?

Tags: sql

Is there a possibility that I can use AND/ OR operators at the same time or just either of them when doing a query?

Here is my code that I can use if I want to use either of `employee_id_name` and `resolved_date`:

```
WHERE 
    employee_id_name = '" . $xid . "' 
    OR resolved_date = '" . $date . "'
```

Here is what I use if I want to use both:

```
WHERE 
    employee_id_name = '" . $xid . "' 
    AND resolved_date = '" . $date . "'
```

Is it possible to combine this two where clauses? If I want to do a query using both `employee_id_name` and `resolved_date` ... and if I also want to query using either of them...

**UPDATE**

I want to be able to use both `employee_id_name` and `resolved_date` at the same time but there would be time as well where I only want to use either of them... now I don't want to keep changing my code with `AND` and `OR` everytime I execute a query.

Comment: What are you trying to achive?

Comment: The first query, also gives you the results of the second one, right?

Comment: I don't get it. OR is not exclusive here, if it is that what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

You can't combine it unless you add a 3rd parameter to decide if you want `AND` or `OR`. Here I've used `$querycondition` which can be 1 or 2. This isn't good PHP syntax of course: I leave that to you

```
WHERE
  (1= $querycondition AND
        (employee_id_name = '" . $xid . "' OR resolved_date = '" . $date . "')
  )
  OR
  (2= $querycondition AND
        (employee_id_name = '" . $xid . "' AND resolved_date = '" . $date . "')
  )
```

Comment: hi ive tried to use your code but am getting Notice: Undefined variable: querycondition...

Comment: I did say "This isn't good PHP syntax of course: I leave that to you".

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can join **AND** and **OR**.

```
select 1
from table t
where a = b
and (b = c or b = d)
;
```

Brackets are not strictily neccessary.

Your select is an entirely different resultset if you simply change or with and. So you must know what the select should do.

In the first case, you find all records where the name matches OR the date. In the second case you find ONLY records where the name matches and in the same record also the date.

**Means:**
The first query finds also records where the name is different if the date is valid, as only one of the clauses must match. In the AND query ALL clauses must match on a single record in order to yield it to the resultset.

Comment: *Brackets are not strictily necessary* but its good practice when dealing with AND and OR

Comment: Right that's why I wrote them and mentioned that they are not abslutely necessary. It's hard to see the dependcies on a more complex query.